# Media Query is not working on one page html

Tags: html, responsive-design, media-queries

i'm just wondering why i can't apply media query in this one page while the other pages can...
can anybody tell me why??

this is the link,
http://blackbox-webstudio.com/demo/isamare/album1.html

i tried to create media query for 768px resolution (ipad potrait view), it was successful for other pages, but not with this one...

is it because of the responsiveslide.js??
but i used that javascript also in that web homepage and the query is working..

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but your query.css is not included in the head of this page, but it is included on the homepage.